# How to add checkbox alongside button in linearlayout android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a linear layout in which I want to insert a checkbox on left and a button on its right.
Also, it should be in for loop so as to create many number of such combination in that single linear layout.

```
    final LinearLayout LayoutRight = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutbars_register);
    LayoutRight.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutRight.setWeightSum(1f);

            final LinearLayout.LayoutParams pR1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            pR1.weight = 0.3f;

            final LinearLayout.LayoutParams pR2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            pR2.weight = 0.7f;


              for (int i = l; i <= lastCounter; i++) {

                tick = new CheckBox(RegisterActivity.this);
                tick.setId(10000 + l);
                tick.setOnClickListener(tick_Click);
                LayoutRight.addView(tick, pR1);

                pdR = new Button(RegisterActivity.this);
                pdR.setText(l + ". ");
                pdR.setId(l);
                pdR.setWidth(800);
                pdR.setTextSize(17);
                pdR.setGravity(Gravity.START);
                pdR.setOnClickListener(pdRclass);
                LayoutRight.addView(pdR, pR2);

                l++;
            }
```

I'm setting 1f as the setWeightSum; 0.3f and 0.7f and childs weight.
With this code I'm getting output as [this](http://s16.postimg.org/v4ep67ged/image.jpg)
But I want my output exactly like [this](http://s15.postimg.org/a4c31fpm3/image.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Layout orientation Like this  **LayoutRight.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);**
not VERTICAL

Comment: with this i'm getting output as - [this] (http://s22.postimg.org/za4rd786p/image.jpg) - when my loop works from 1 to 5

Comment: you need to add LayoutRight  layout in another layout and set orientation of the parent layout to VERTICAL.

Comment: Keeping LayoutRight as parent layout, I created a new layout-
  final LinearLayout newLR = new LinearLayout(RegisterActivity.this);
  newLR.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  newLR.setWeightSum(1f);
changed some lines in for loop-
                newLR.addView(tick, pR1); and newLR.addView(pdR, pR2);
     then i've added a line before for closes - LayoutRight.addView(newLR);

This gives me error.

Comment: add Error log trace in question

Comment: When I put - LayoutRight.addView(newLR); - right outside the for loop the i get result as same as - http://s22.postimg.org/za4rd786p/image.jpg

Error log when - LayoutRight.addView(newLR); - is inside for loop, right before the loop closes - http://textuploader.com/ak0b3

Comment: http://textuploader.com/akw6e is my new code, and http://s15.postimg.org/rijq43oh7/image.jpg is my new output. I'm still not able to get the required output. Because my lastCounter value is 5 and l value is 1. So I need to have 5 rows of CheckBox and Button, whereas the output has only 1 row. I think that the HORIZANTAL thing is making it move onto right of linear layout. Henceforth, it is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

LayoutRight.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL)?

I'm not cool enough to comment so...

Android [weight doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) says the effected attribute needs to be set to 0dp so try this.

```
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams pR1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        0,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        pR1.weight = 0.3f;

        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams pR2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        0,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        pR2.weight = 0.7f;
```

don't forget to keep your orientation horizontal!

Comment: http://textuploader.com/akw6e is my new code, and 
http://s15.postimg.org/rijq43oh7/image.jpg is my new output.
I'm still not able to get the required output. Because my lastCounter value is 5 and l value is 1. So I need to have 5 rows of CheckBox and Button, whereas the output has only 1 row.
I think that the HORIZANTAL thing is making it move onto right of linear layout. Henceforth, it is not visible.

Comment: Setting attribute *width* and *gravity* for your button(s) is unnecessary.  Also if you if need 5 rows either start the count at 0 or set lastCounter = 6.  *are you sure **lastCounter** is not 1?

Comment: I'm 100% sure that l is 1 and lastCounter is 5. 'gravity.START' is to bring the text on the left of the button which is needed. I commented out 'pdR.setWidth(800);' and this is xml file part and for part  - [link](http://textuploader.com/ao93l) - and I'm still not getting expected output.